# Есть сайт и нужно добавить на определенную страницу ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel

Есть проект и это голый html, css, js. И нужно внедрить ReactJS на определенную страницу, что бы оно работало как веб-приложение. Как мне это сделать не нарушив архитектуру сайта?  Т.е эту страницу я перепишу под jsx, К этой странице уже подключены, css, js файлы, как основные так и для конкретной этой странице.

Comment: Вы используете какой-то сборщик для Вашего сайта?

Comment: К сожалению нет, это обычный голый сайт на html, css, js. Нужно внедрить на одну страницу реакт

Answer (score 1):

- внутри **html** страницы подключите *React* через **CDN** ([ссылка как](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html)).
- чтобы использовать `JSX`, подключите так же `babel` через **CDN** `<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>`.